# copy ami using lambda function fails with kms key inaccessible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ami

I am using the below boto3 python script to copy AMI from target AWS account to source account. The lambda script is running on the source account.

It initializes the copy of AMI on the source account from the target account. But gives this error:

```
"AMI snapshot copy failed with error: Given key ID is not accessible"
```

The KMS key used here is of the source account which has the IAM role of the lambda function attached to it already with kms:* permissions.

```
import boto3

target_account_id = 'TXXXXXXXXXXX'
source_account_id = 'SXXXXXXXXXXX'
source_profile = 'aws-cli-profile'
role_on_target_account = 'arn:aws:iam::TTTTTTTTTT:role/CopyAmiLambdaFunction'
source_region = 'eu-west-2'
target_region = 'eu-west-1'

def get_main_session():
    """
    This function returns the main session of the Master/Mgmt account.
    """
    # session = boto3.Session(profile_name=source_profile, region_name=source_region)
    print("Creating local session")
    session = boto3.Session(region_name=source_region)
    return session

def get_temp_cred(session, role_arn, account_id):
    """
    This function returns the temporary credentials using the trust
    relationship
    """
    print("Getting temp credentials")
    get_cred_client = session.client('sts')
    get_cred_response = get_cred_client.assume_role(\
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        RoleSessionName=account_id)
    return get_cred_response['Credentials']


def get_temp_session(cred, region):
    """
    This function returns the temporary session, using the temporary
    AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey and the SessionToken returned by the
    temporary credentials
    """
    print("Creating temp session")
    temp_session = boto3.Session(\
        aws_access_key_id=cred['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=cred['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=cred['SessionToken'],
        region_name=region)
    return temp_session


def add_launch_permission(session, region):
    """
    This function reurns the list of filtered AMI
    """
    print("Retreiving list of images")
    ec2 = session.resource('ec2', region_name = region)
    images = ec2.images.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'name', 'Values':['amiiiiii-xxxx-iddd']}])
    for i in images:
        response = i.modify_attribute(
            Attribute='launchPermission',
            LaunchPermission={
                'Add': [
                    {
                        'UserId': source_account_id
                    }
                ]
            },
            OperationType='add'
        )
        print(response)
        
    for i in images:
        devices = i.block_device_mappings
        for device in devices:
            if 'Ebs' in device:
                snapshot_id = device["Ebs"]["SnapshotId"]
                snapshot = ec2.Snapshot(snapshot_id)
                snapshot.modify_attribute(
                            Attribute = 'createVolumePermission',
                            CreateVolumePermission = {
                                'Add' : [{ 'UserId': source_account_id }]
                                },
                            OperationType = 'add',
                            )

    return images

def copy_ami(session, source_region, target_region, ami_id):
    """
    This function is used to copy the unencrypted AMI to encrypted AMI using KMS key in BU account.
    """
    print("Start copy of AMI")
    for i in ami_id:
        client = session.client('ec2', region_name = source_region)
        response = client.copy_image(
            Description='Encrypted Golden Image',
            Encrypted=True,
            KmsKeyId='arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:SXXXXXXXXXX:key/fabc4ee4-2c73-4c8d-a93e-ca572053a124',
            Name='Demo-Copy-AMI',
            SourceImageId=i.id,
            SourceRegion=target_region
        )
        return response["ImageId"]

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    #Get Main Session
    session = get_main_session()
    #Get Temp Cred
    temp_cred = get_temp_cred(session, role_on_target_account, target_account_id)
    #Get Temp Session
    temp_session = get_temp_session(temp_cred, target_region)
    #Add Launch permission for AMI
    ami_id = add_launch_permission(temp_session , target_region)
    print(ami_id)
    #Copy AMI
    image_id = copy_ami(session, source_region, target_region, ami_id)
    print(image_id)
```

Comment: I presume you are saying that the error is caused by the `KmsKeyId` supplied in the `copy_image()` command? I wonder if it needs a [key policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html) to permit the IAM Role to use it?

Comment: the script works other way around i,e pushing image from source to target account with KMS key. However i want this to work by pulling the image from target account.

Comment: Oh! Yes, it's confusing with the naming 'source' and 'target' being backwards (copying from Target to Source). Can you change it so that the `copy_image()` command is issued against the 'source' account instead?

Comment: copy_ami is already using the session for source account

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that it works when you try to copy and AMI from 'source' to 'target', but does _not_ work when it goes from 'target' to 'source'? Does it work if you try it in the EC2 management console? When it fails, do you receive an error? What is in the `response`?

Comment: yes, copy is from target to source, the error on EC2 ami console page is "the specified KEyID is inaccessible"